# Can't open Angular application in the browser, that is running from docker container

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I'm pretty new to Docker and I'm trying to create a docker image that clones a github repo with a very simple Angular application and runs it in the container. Then I want to access this running Angular application in my browser.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN git clone https://github.com/path-to-repo.git

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/docker-angular

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN npm install

CMD ng serve --port 5000
```

I build the image and I'm running the container with the following command

```
docker container run -d -p 5000:5000 --name [container-name] [image-name]
```

When i check the logs i see that the application is running successfully in the container, but when i try to access it in my browser on localhost:5000 it's not there.
This is the output when I run docker container ls:

```
806a71aa5972        angular-app         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   sample-angular
```

Can I access the application that is running in the container from the browser and how should I do that?

Comment: you have to expose port 5000 from your dockerFile

Comment: EXPOSE 5000
CMD ng serve --port 5000

Comment: Never build from any image :latest, also expose the port in the Dockerfile with EXPOSE 5000

Comment: I exposed the port but that didn't work for me.

Comment: What solved my issue was the following: Since I'm running Docker on a Windows 10 machine i had to modify the CMD command to "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0" and also expose port 49153 which is Angular specific.